# writing above the current position of cursor in book with quill

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to write at the position (see the arrow in the image).
I have written co-ordinates of a village in the game. **I do not want to erase co-ordinates**. But want to write above it. it seems that <kbd>left</kbd> button does not move my current writing position to backward.

Is there any method to preserve the current text it the book and write in space above text that I had left?

[image]

Comment: Try `Shift` + `-->` or `<--`. I don't know if this works, but you could even try `Shift` + `^` (up-arrow)

Comment: yes i tried the shift + <- ; but unfortunately it didnt work. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Much like signs, you cannot enter text in a place before the end of the page. To solve your problem, I would write the coordinates on a piece of paper or something, delete the text after where you want to type, and redo the rest of the page.